# Why do we need to use threads for running Kafka consumers? And how many threads do we need?

Tags: java, multithreading, apache-kafka

I am relatively new to Java (I have some experience with Scala) and currently trying to learn about Kafka. I came across the following example in this [tutorial](https://www.udemy.com/course/apache-kafka/) (I am adding the code mostly for reference):

```
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecords;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer;
import org.apache.kafka.common.errors.WakeupException;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;

public class ConsumerDemoWithThread {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ConsumerDemoWithThread().run();
    }

    private ConsumerDemoWithThread() {

    }

    private void run() {
        Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ConsumerDemoWithThread.class.getName());

        String bootstrapServers = "127.0.0.1:9092";
        String groupId = "my-sixth-application";
        String topic = "first_topic";

        // latch for dealing with multiple threads
        CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

        // create the consumer runnable
        logger.info("Creating the consumer thread");
        Runnable myConsumerRunnable = new ConsumerRunnable(
                bootstrapServers,
                groupId,
                topic,
                latch
        );

        // start the thread
        Thread myThread = new Thread(myConsumerRunnable);
        myThread.start();

        // add a shutdown hook
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(() -> {
            logger.info("Caught shutdown hook");
            ((ConsumerRunnable) myConsumerRunnable).shutdown();
            try {
                latch.await();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            logger.info("Application has exited");
        }

        ));

        try {
            latch.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            logger.error("Application got interrupted", e);
        } finally {
            logger.info("Application is closing");
        }
    }

    public class ConsumerRunnable implements Runnable {

        private final CountDownLatch latch;
        private final KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer;
        private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ConsumerRunnable.class.getName());

        public ConsumerRunnable(String bootstrapServers,
                                String groupId,
                                String topic,
                                CountDownLatch latch) {
            this.latch = latch;

            // create consumer configs
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
            properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());
            properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());
            properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId);
            properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");

            // create consumer
            consumer = new KafkaConsumer<String, String>(properties);
            // subscribe consumer to our topic(s)
            consumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList(topic));
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // poll for new data
            try {
                while (true) {
                    ConsumerRecords<String, String> records =
                            consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(100)); // new in Kafka 2.0.0

                    for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {
                        logger.info("Key: " + record.key() + ", Value: " + record.value());
                        logger.info("Partition: " + record.partition() + ", Offset:" + record.offset());
                    }
                }
            } catch (WakeupException e) {
                logger.info("Received shutdown signal!");
            } finally {
                consumer.close();
                // tell our main code we're done with the consumer
                latch.countDown();
            }
        }

        public void shutdown() {
            // the wakeup() method is a special method to interrupt consumer.poll()
            // it will throw the exception WakeUpException
            consumer.wakeup();
        }
    }
}
```

I am mainly trying to understand:

1. What are the benefits of using a thread for running the
   consumer? I (*I thought Kafka abstracts the distribution of load across consumers anyways*)
2. When we use `Thread myThread = new Thread(myConsumerRunnable);`  does
   that run in a single thread or across multiple threads?
3. Why do we fire the shutdown hook via a separate thread? (*To my understanding from inspecting the method, it seems more like a Java thing than a Kafka thing*)

Comment: Looks like the threads are just meant to represent the multiple consumers on a single runtime, you'd often have them in separate instances (microservices).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What are the benefits of using a thread for running the consumer? I (I
> thought Kafka abstracts the distribution of load across consumers
> anyways)

As you can see, the consumer starts an infinite loop in the `run` method. Starting it as a new thread lets you do more things in the main thread while the consumer is already active.

> When we use Thread myThread = new Thread(myConsumerRunnable); does that run in a > single thread or across multiple threads?

Creating the Thread object does not start the new thread yet. It's `myThread.start();` where the new thread starts execution. Your example program has a main thread and a consumer thread. The main thread actually waits for the shutdown signal through the `CountDownLatch latch`, so arguably it would have been possible to avoid the consumer thread.

> Why do we fire the shutdown hook via a separate thread? (To my understanding
> from inspecting the method, it seems more like a Java thing than a Kafka thing)

It's a java thing. The shutdown hook thread is not actually executed until shutdown happens. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook(java.lang.Thread)